# how to add more frontend feature to front-end editing (alias, association...)

Tags: joomla-3.x, editor, front-end, alias

Front-end editing in Joomla 3 is a bit limited. How could I add more features to it such as the "alias" or the "association" tab, or maybe to get on the front-end the same features than in backend?

Comment: If you want the article form to be customized for front-end, i think you can try SEBOLD for that.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: @johnny_s: I don't understand what you mean by framework? I am using Joomla 3.3.1, the admin template is isis, the front end template is protostar.

Comment: Thanks @Sasivarnakumar, I am looking for a front-end article edit layout override rather than a component.

Comment: I though you may have been using a custom template. You could do manual template overrides if you are familiar with them, alternatively you may want to have a look at K2 (http://getk2.org/) - it provides the ability to add custom fields quite easily -although I don't think you want a component.

Comment: I am familliar with template override, but not with php so I have trouble adding the correct code in the correct file so thta I can get the alias field, the association tab and so on on front end

Answer (score 1):

First of all - alternate template (place template file in your template/html/com_content directory).

Article to help you: http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla

Then - add new editing options to altered template. You can use existing options as refference.